# Show all content type fields in list edit form

Tags: 2013, list, content-type, content

I want to show all content type fields when editing a list in Sharepoint 2013.

At the moment I am getting a drop down window and I have to choose between content types.

Is there any way to show them all on the same page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot show fields from different content types while editing an `Item` and this is the SharePoint's OOB functionality.

An `Item` in SharePoint is associated to only one `Content Type`. So while editing an Item it is theoretically incorrect to expect fields from the other content type, to be displayed on the Form.

Also I will never recommend to go ahead and customize your `Edit Form` to show fields from other content types.